# Error: "watch is not supported on resources of kind \"nodes.metrics.k8s.io\""

Tags: metrics-server

I am running metrics server (   k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.6.2) in my EKS cluster (V 1.24) and I am seeing this message showing up 100's of times in a trace of the system:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "watch is not supported on resources of kind \"nodes.metrics.k8s.io\"",
  "reason": "MethodNotAllowed",
  "details": {
    "group": "metrics.k8s.io",
    "kind": "nodes"
  },
  "code": 405
}
```

Trace Information:
URL: /apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes

x-remote-user   system:serviceaccount:cattle-system:cattle

I am assuming this has something to do with rancher.  I have searched high and low and can't find any mention of this exact error message.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

x-remote-user system:serviceaccount:cattle-system:cattle

I am assuming this has something to do with rancher. I have searched high and low and can't find any mention of this exact error message.

What might be the problem?